# query mongodb with spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I am connecting MongoDB to Spark and I want to load data using a query.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").options(collection='test', query = {'name' :'jack'}).load()
df.show()
```

But it returns me the whole collection. How can I reproduce the same thing as this query db.test.find({'name':'jack'}) in Spark ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter` or `where` to specify the condition:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.filter(col("name") == "jack")
```

It will converted to an [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/scala/datasets-and-sql/#scala-dataset-filters):

> When using filters with DataFrames or Spark SQL, the underlying Mongo Connector code constructs an aggregation pipeline to filter the data in MongoDB before sending it to Spark.